# How to consume external webservice

Tags: apex, wsdl2apex, apex-webservice

I got the requirement where I need to consume the WSDL from Workday and create/update contact records in Salesforce. Can someone of you please assist me in how to utilize a WSDL from Workday into apex. Any sample code to implement the same will be more helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If the WSDL is fairly basic you can use a tool provided from Salesforce called [WSDL2Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm). It will generate Apex classes that allow you to callout to the web methods exposed by the web service. You will also need to add a [Remote Site setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_remote_site_settings.htm) to allow the callout to the target URL to occur.

Note that this will generate both synchronous and asynchronous classes for performing the callout. The latter is for use from Visualforce pages if you don't want to busy wait for the response.

---

There are limits to what type of SOAP callouts Apex supports and the type of WSDLs that WSDL2Apex can handle. See [Supported WSDL Features](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm#supported_wsdls_topic-title).

You may get some further flexibility by using the [open source version of WSDL2Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/09/announcing-open-source-wsdl2apex-generator.html). Or you may need to resort to manually forming the HTTP callouts and response parsing.

Finally, in the self promotion category, I've made an independent version of [WSDL2Apex that is distributed by my employer](http://www.fishofprey.com/2014/11/dreamforce-2014-presentation-improved.html). This can overcome a number of limitations from the built in version, but is still ultimately limited by what Apex supports via `WebServiceCallout.invoke`.